# React Native : Fetch Can't retrieve value of token when passed by reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to get the response from the code below. The expected response is a 400. The when I explicitly type out ut in the fetch call,it works. But when I pass ut as a variable, I get the error below

**Note:** retrieveUserToken() get the token from AsyncStorage.

WHat works: When I type this in the header: it works.

````
'Authorization': "Bearer eyJskfjvksndvjnsdknvlkandlkcnals"

Doesn't work: 

```'Authorization': "Bearer "+ ut

```onPress={async () => {
                       

                        const ut = await retrieveUserToken("token")
                        const data = {id: "myID", password:"mypass"}

                        await fetch("http://MY-URL", {
                          method: "POST",
                          
                          headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                            'Authorization':
                              "Bearer " + ut
                          },
                          body: JSON.stringify(data),
                        }).then(response => JSON.stringify( response))
                        .then(result => console.log(result))
                        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
                      }}


ERROR:  {"type":"default","status":401,"ok":false,"headers":{"map":{"content-length":"0","server":"Kestrel","www-authenticate":"Bearer error=\"invalid_token\"","date":"Fri, 21 Aug 2020 03:23:00 GMT","content-type":"text/plain"}},"url":"http://63.35.183.253:9054/api/appointment","bodyUsed":false,"_bodyInit":{"_data":{"size":0,"offset":0,"blobId":"F5F055F9-8C4C-434D-AA39-11B58B0CE290","type":"text/plain","name":"appointment.txt","__collector":{}}},"_bodyBlob":{"_data":{"size":0,"offset":0,"blobId":"F5F055F9-8C4C-434D-AA39-11B58B0CE290","type":"text/plain","name":"appointment.txt","__collector":{}}}}
````

Answer (score 0):

> `"www-authenticate":"Bearer error=\"invalid_token\"`

That implies `ut === 'error=\"invalid_token\"'`. I.e., you have a problem retrieving the token. When you look back at it:

> `const ut = await retrieveUserToken("token")`

Are you sure you want to pass **the string** `"token"` as arg?

Comment: You're right. I want to 1 retrieve the token from Async Storage ( that is what the retrieveUserToken() does) then pass the token to the fetch to access the resource. This makes the code more dynamic. How can I solve this ?

Comment: How do I get the quotes off a string? When I log this const newHeader =  `Bearer ${token}`; console.log(newHeader), I get : Bearer "eyJsbfhbjsfhb"  I was expecting Bearer eyJsbfhbjsfhb. How do I rectify this ?

Comment: No worries. I've solved it. I parsed the token to get it as a JSON object. I don't know if I should cry right now. It has been such a pain. Thank you so much dalmo